# undefined method `original_filename' for String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload

I'm trying to implement a csv upload functionality WITHOUT using gems such as `paperclip`. Here's the view:

```
 %h1 Add Users From CSV
 = form_tag(:action => "upload",:multipart => true,:method => :post) do
   = file_field_tag 'csv'
   = submit_tag 'Upload'
```

And here's the controller:

```
def upload
  csv_io = params[:csv]

  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', csv_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(csv_io.read)
  end

  redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Successfully uploaded csv!"
end
```

But I got this error message when I'm uploading a csv called `data.csv`

```
undefined method `original_filename' for "data.csv":String
```

I just followed the official Rails guide, but it's still getting error. Can anyone suggest some solutions?

NOTE: I just need to read data from the csv file and it does not need to be saved persistently on server.

Comment: My memory is that depending on the size of the file being uploaded it may come back as a string or a File object.  You don't need paperclip.  You probably should look into ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you're passing the arguments to `form_tag`, all your arguments are getting treated as part of the first `form_tag` parameter `url_for_options`, instead of going in part to the second parameter `options` (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag for the method definition).

Per the guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files, you can use the following syntax to achieve what you want:

```
form_tag({:action => "upload"},:multipart => true)
```

You don't need to set `:method` because it defaults to `post`.

Comment: Now it says `No such file or directory - /Users/XXX/Desktop/projects/myapp/public/uploads/data.csv`. (I'm using a macbook.)

Comment: Where in the code is it coming from? The only code you show is _writing_ to that location. Do all those directories exist (e.g. ../public and ../public/uploads)?

Comment: Never mind. Obviously adding a `uploads`  directory is critical in file uploading.