# Import excel data into database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I'm searching for import excel data into mySQL database. I refer "Ruby on Rails - Railscasts #396 Importing Csv And Excel ". Going with that, I get the error

```
dynamic constant assignment Subject = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new ^
```

Can anyone explain and give solution. My codes are, in model.rb,

```
  def self.import(file)
allowed_attributes = [ "module_number", "module_name"]
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file.path)
header = spreadsheet.row(1)
(2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
  row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
  subject = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new
  subject.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*allowed_attributes)
  subject.save!
end
```

end

```
 def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then
     Roo::Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xls" then
    Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xlsx" then
     Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xml" then
    Roo::XML.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
else
  raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
end
```

end

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ruby constants starts with a capital character. You have to write `subject` instead of `Subject`. In your case ruby treats `Subject`as an constant and complains about changing a constant.

Comment: But it is a model name. Subject = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new
      Subject.attributes = row_to_hash
      Subject.create!

Comment: Ya thank you. I notice that now only. Your point is correct. I try this. Sorry for misconception.

Comment: "No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/oo_20161027-13123-106anlt/roo_workbook.xml"   Now I get this type of error. I am not understand with that error

Comment: `rb_sysopen` is a new error. This error has to occour some where else within your code. Without the code I can only guess what's going wrong. It seems like `roo` tries to open a file which does not exits or you don't have write permissions to `/tmp`

Comment: I get the error as "undefined method `original_filename' for "/tmp/RackMultipart20161101-6013-1duaki1.xls":String". what type of error is this? is it a storage error???

Comment: I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755189/undefined-method-original-filename-for-string is your issue too